# lectura de archivo txt en java

Tags: java, archivo

hola buenas tardes estoy desarrollando un programa en java donde se lee un documento txt linea por linea la cosa es que no se muy bien como hacer para que recorra la linea

aqui es donde leo el metodo de fileReader y bufferedReader

```
public static String procesarArchivo(ManejoArchivos ma) throws  IOException{
        try(BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("texto.txt"))){
            return ma.leerArchivo(br);
        }
    }
```

y aqui donde esta mi metodo main y intento recorrer linea por linea pero nadamas se queda en la primer linea

```
public static void main(String [] arg) {
        try{
        String linea = null;
        String lineas = procesarArchivo((BufferedReader br) -> br.readLine());
        while(lineas != null){
            System.out.println(lineas);
            break;
        }
        }catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: en ningún lado le estás diciendo que cambie de línea y ciertamente, `lineas` no es nulo porque es la primera línea. El camino para ésto es que uses una condición en el while que revise si _la siguiente línea_ es nula (obteniéndola de paso)

Comment: entonces como lo dejaria

Comment: entonces como lo dejaria   while(lineas == linea){
            System.out.println(lineas);
        }